# Recognize that a value is bool in a template

Tags: c++, c++17

This short C++17 program:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> void output(T x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<decltype(x)>::value) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << " is integral" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << x << " is not integral" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char x = 65;
    output(x);

    bool t = true;
    output(t);

    return 0;
}
```

Has this output:

```
65 is integral
1 is integral
```

In the template function named `output`, how can one detect that the argument `x` is boolean and not a number?

The plan is to output the value with `std::cout << std::boolalpha <<`, but only if the type is `bool`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`std::is_integral` checks if a type is one of the following types: `bool`, `char`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `wchar_t`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` ([source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral)). If you want to check if a type is the same as another type, `std::is_same` can be used. Both can be combined to get the wanted result:

```
template <typename T> void output(T x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<decltype(x)>::value && !std::is_same<decltype(x), bool>::value) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << " is integral but not a boolean" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << x << " is not integral" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

or, since we already know the type of `decltype(x)`, which is `T`:

```
template <typename T> void output(T x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<T, bool>::value) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << " is integral but not a boolean" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << x << " is not integral" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Another way can be to use a template specialization. This makes sure the other overload is being used to handle the boolean value.

```
template <typename T> void output(T x)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value) {
        std::cout << static_cast<int>(x) << " is integral but not a boolean" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << x << " is not integral" << std::endl;
    }
}

template <> void output(bool x)
{
    std::cout << x << " is a boolean" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: maybe change the output to `"is integral but not bool"` / `"is bool or not integral"`

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace fmt {
  namespace adl {
    template<class T>
    void output( std::ostream& os, T const& t ) {
      os << t;
    }
    void output( std::ostream& os, bool const& b ) {
      auto old = os.flags();
      os << std::boolalpha << b;
      if (!( old & std::ios_base::boolalpha) )
        os << std::noboolalpha; // restore state
    }
    template<class T>
    void output_helper( std::ostream& os, T const& t ) {
      output(os, t); // ADL
    }
  }
  template<class T>
  std::ostream& output( std::ostream& os, T const& t ) {
    adl::output_helper( os, t );
    return os;
  }
}
```

now `fmt::output( std::cout, true )` prints `true`, while `fmt::output( std::cout, 7 )` prints `7`.

You can extend `fmt::output` by creating a function in either `fmt::adl` or in the type `T`'s namespace called `output` that takes a `std::ostream&` and a `T const&`.